# Displaying json data in input field with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs

I would to display JSON data in html input fields using AngularJS.
Here's the code.

I have two HTML files. First HTML file contains a table which displays the json data. When you click in a row then it opens a modal window with a form (second HTML file).

Here's the Code: JSON data

```
var examples = [
   { 'id': '1', 'fname': 'john' },
   { 'id': '2', 'fname': 'bonnie' },
   { 'id': '3', 'fname': 'joey' }
];
```

Here's the Code: (First HTML file)

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="item in examples" ng-click="open(this.item)">
   <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
</tr>
...
```

Second HTML file:

```
...
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" id="firstVal" value="">
...
```

My Controller:

```
...
$scope.open = function (item) {
   console.log(item.id);
   $("#firstVal").val(item.id);
};
...
```

It doesn't insert the value "id" in the input field. How can I do this with AngularJS or jQuery?? In the console I'm getting the value of id.

Comment: how do I think in angular if i have jquery background... get away with ids.. thats not how you work in angular... using $(#...) in angular is never never needed...

Comment: add `ng-model` to the `<input ... />` and set its value

Comment: Try: placeholder="{{item.id}}", no need for JQuery as pointed out above

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" ng-model="selectedId">
```

and

```
$scope.open = function (item) {
   console.log(item.id);
   $scope.selectedId = item.Id
};
```

Comment: Hej entre.. I've tried your solution but it doesn't work. In the modal window the inputfield is remaining empty.

Comment: Do you have different controllers?? Is your console.log working??

Comment: I've found the problem. in my controller I've forgotten in my modalInstance variable the point `resolve: { selected: function() {  return $scope.selectedId }}`

Comment: thats where I was coming to... if you have different controllers, then you would need to pass the data between them..

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure your second HTML is using the same controller (shared scope). Moreover, it is always advised to use a dot notation when accessing scope items. In this case you would suggest the same as entre but with a minor modification:

```
$scope.open = function (item) {
   $scope.selectedObj.id = item.Id
};
```

And in the form HTML (once you have the same controller working there):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" ng-model="selectedObj.id">
```

**UPDATE**
Here's a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/aqs9vLd8/1/
Note how *$scope.selectedObj* needs to be initialized first as an object (empty).

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thx Rhaziel for your post. I've found my solution. You can read it in my last comment above. :)